# Need an algorithm to find near-duplicate text values

Tags: php, algorithm, duplicates, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I run a photo website where users are free to enter any tag they like, even tags not used before. As a result, a photo of a tag may sometimes be tagged as "insect" whilst somebody else tags it as "insects".

I'd like to keep the free-tagging capability, yet would like to have a way to filter out such near-duplicates. The total collection of tags is currently at 1,500. My idea is to read all of them from the DB into mem and then run an alghoritm on it that displays "suspects".

My idea of a suspect is that x% of the characters in the string are the same (same char and order), where x is configurable. I could probably code a really inefficient way to do this but I was wondering if there is an existing solution to this problem?

Edit: Forgot to mention: just sorting the tags isn't enough, as that would require me to go through the entire set to find dupes.

Comment: [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or [Jaro Winkler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) can be used to determine similarity of strings.

In PHP you have the [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function which performs such a comparison, or the [`levenshtein`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [fuzzy string match](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) and/or something like [soundex matching](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)

Comment: @birryree I wish you would have posted that as an answer rather than a comment :) Didn't know about similar_text, looks like what I need. I do worry about performance though. With 1500 tags that would be 1500 x 1500 calls to this function.

Comment: @Ferdy - I did post it as an answer but deleted it because other answers seemed closer to your problem. Yes, there could be a performance issue, and `similar_text`, for example, is a cubic-time function. You can probably perform some optimizations up front by grouping tags into buckets (i.e. break up tags by first letter) such that you'd only have to examine one set of tags. You could create a 'same tag' list for the 'primary' tag you want, i.e. 'insect' is the main one but 'insects' is related to it.

Comment: @birryree Thanks. I'm going to try to use similar_text and see how it performs. This concerns an admin function so awesome performance is not required. I do need to get all the suspect duplicates of the entire set, otherwise I would have to open each individual tags.

Answer (score 2):

There are some flaws in your logic. For example, what happens when the plural of an object is different from the singular (i.e. person vs. people or even candy vs. candies).

If English is the primary language, check out [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) which allows phonetic matches. Also consider using a crowd-sourced synonym model where users can create links to existing tags.

Comment: What flaw? I mentioned in the article that x should be configurable. You are right though that a large difference in singular and plural would a) force me to set x very low b) the alghoritm would miss it.

Comment: What if English is not the first language when there's rather need to check for multiple languages?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the algorithm you are looking for is approximate string matching. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching.

by a given word you can match it to list of words and if the 'distance' is close add it to suspects.

A fast implementation is to use dynamic programming like the Needleman–Wunsch algorithm.
I have made a blog example of this in C# where you can configure the 'distance' using a matrix character lookup file.
http://kunuk.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/dynamic-programming-example-with-c-using-needleman-wunsch-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

Is "either contains either" fine? You could do a SQL query something like this, if your images are in a database (which would only make sense):

```sql
SELECT * FROM ImageTags WHERE INSTR('theNewTag', TagName) > 0 OR INSTR(TagName, 'theNewTag') > 0 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Often that would match but I'm afraid that would not catch all duplicates. Example: mammalia vs mammals.

Comment: @Ferdy: Well, it's a bit hard when it gets to that; say retractable vs. intractable or something. 2 letters' difference, but entirely different words... When the query doesn't match it, have users manually select synonyms like on Stack Overflow or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this efficiently I would suggest some sort of JavaScript implementation that displays possibilities as the user is typing in a tag that they want. Not only will it save the user time to happily see 5 suggestions as they type. It will automatically stop them from typing "suspects" when "suspect" shows up as a suggestion. That is, of course, unless they really want "suspects" as a point of urgency.

You could load a huge list of words and as the user types narrow them down. I get the feeling that this could be very simplistic esp if you want to anticipate correctly spelled words. If someone misses a letter, they'll probably go back to fix it when they see a list of suggestions that isn't at all what they meant to type. And when they do correctly type a word it'll pop up in the suggestions.

Comment: The thing is, I already have an auto suggesting list. If you type "inse" it will suggest "insects" yet some users seem to not care and still use "insect".